# Highchart gauge not displaying min/max value in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, neo4j

I have a weird issue. I am displaying data from a neo4j database onto the highcharts. I am able to retrieve the data, but when i try to put it onto the charts, some of it doesnt display. Here is my gauge code

**CustomGauge.vue**

```
<template>
  <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";

export default {
  name: "CustomGuage",
  components: {
  highcharts: Chart
  },
  props: ["data", "title",   "range1", "range2", "min", "max"],
  data() {
    return {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      type: "gauge",

      // plotBackgroundColor: null,
      // plotBackgroundImage: null,
      // plotBorderWidth: 0,
      // plotShadow: false,

      //marginBottom: 170,
    },

     credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

    title: {
      text: this.title,
      align: "left"
    
    },

    pane: {
      startAngle: -150,
      endAngle: 150,
      size: 200,
      background: {
         borderWidth: 0
        }
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      min: this.min,
      max: this.max,
      // tickPixelInterval: 30,
      // tickWidth: 2,
      // tickColor: "#666",
      plotBands: [
        {
          from: 0,
          to: this.range1,
          color: "#55BF3B" // green
        },
        {
          from: this.range1,
          to: this.range2,
          color: "#DDDF0D" // yellow
        },
        {
          from: this.range2,
          to: 1000,
          color: "#DF5353" // red
        }
      ]
    },

    series: [
      {
        data: this.data
        // tooltip: {
        //   valueSuffix: " km/h"
        // }
      },
      // // {
      // //   data: this.target,
      // //   dataLabels: {
      // //     enabled: true,
      // //     format: "Target: {y}%",
      // //     verticalAlign: "bottom",
      // //     borderWidth: 0
      // //     //useHTML: true,
      // //   },
       
      // }
    ]
  }
};
},
 watch: {
data(newVal) {
  this.chartOptions.series[0].data = newVal;
 }
 }

};
```

I define my chart like this

```
<CustomGuage :title="gaugeTitle1" :data="gaugeData1" :min="gauge1min" :max="gauge1max" :range1="gauge1Range1" :range2="gauge1Range2" />
```

I initialize it in **data()** like this -

```
  gaugeTitle1: [],
  gaugeData1: [],
  gauge1Range1: [],
  gauge1Range2: [],
  gauge1min: [],
  gauge1max: [],
```

Using the neo4j-vuejs connector, i retrieve the data like this -

```
const session19 = this.$neo4j.getSession(); 
// KPI 1
 session19
    .run(
      "match (n:proj) where exists(n.min) return n.name as title,n.min as min,n.max as max,n.range1 
    as range1,n.range2 as range2,n.target AS target, n.current as data"
    )
    .then((res) => {
      // KPI 1-------------------------
      this.data1 = res.records[0].get("data");
      var a = JSON.parse(this.data1);
      this.gaugeData1.push(a);
      console.log(a)

      this.min1 = res.records[0].get("min");
      var b = JSON.parse(this.min1);
      this.gauge1min = b;
      console.log(this.gauge1min)

      this.max1 = res.records[0].get("max");
      var c = JSON.parse(this.max1);
      this.gauge1max = c;
      console.log(this.gauge1max)

      this.title1 = res.records[0].get("title");
      this.gaugeTitle1.push(this.title1)
      console.log(this.gaugeTitle1);
    })
  
    .then(() => {
      session.close();
    });
```

The retrieval of data works fine, i checked in the console.The weird part is if i comment/uncomment or change something in **CustomGauge.vue**, the charts displays perfectly, displays everything perfectly from the database.But once i refresh the page, it is gone. Could someone help me out. thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox? Try to use sample data with the same structure as data from your database. You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj.

Comment: hey , the moment i use sample static data, everything is displayed fine, i feel it has something to do with the way i define this.min etc. the moment i replace this.min with a static value, the chart renders with no issue. The reactivity part that the other person mentioned might make sense, because the moment i comment or uncomment, due to the auto refresh feature of vue.js, i am able to see the chart render. Moment i refresh from browser, its gone

Comment: Have you tried to use setTimeout to mimic dynamic data?

Comment: hey , how do i do that?

Comment: Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-lwdpk?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

Comment: i tried this, it did not work, the data still renders fine, but its like it cant get the min max value at first render, only after i make some changes, it suddenly displays everything perfectly

Comment: And there is no way to reproduce it somehow?

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle or codepen, but i can try. but the issue is only when the data is displayed from the database, if i put hard coded values in customGauge.vue, it works perfectly fine , so i dont know whether showing it in an online editor will show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a reactivity issue.

Instead of

```
this.chartOptions.series[0].data = newVal;
```

Try

```
this.$set(this.chartOptions.series[0], 'data', newVal)
```

Comment: hey, i tried this, but it didnt work, is there anything else you see which might create the issue?